# how to manage the root element via constructor in Active Model Serializer .10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I call an AMS like this:

```
  def me
      render json: current_user, serializer: UserProfile2Serializer, adapter: :json
  end
```

I'd like to get a version of this for caching in our Postgres db. I do this:

```
json = UserProfile2Serializer.new(user)
```

but I need to specify the `adapter: :json`. How do I this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following below:

```
my_hash = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(user, serializer: UserProfile2Serializer, adapter: :json).as_json
render json: my_hash
```

---

According to the [docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#what-does-a-serializable-resource-look-like):

> Outside of the controller the rules are exactly the same as for records. For example:

```
render json: MyModel.new(level: 'awesome'), adapter: :json
```

> would be serialized the same as

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(MyModel.new(level: 'awesome'), adapter: :json).as_json
```